# Определить, есть ли фокус на одном из полей формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь реализовать следующий функционал:

- имеется форма с одним видимым полем и скрытыми элементами;
- при фокусе на видимом поле раскрываются скрытые;
- при разфокусе, если все поля пустые, скрытые элементы снова исчезают.

Возникает проблема, когда фокус переходит по пустым полям - скрытые элементы сворачиваются и занового разворачиваются.
Что делаю не так?

P.S. В идеале бы сделать так, чтобы поля не сворачивались даже при клике вне поля, но внутри формы.

```js
$('.foot-form').each(function() {
  var form = $(this),
    inputs = form.find('input, textarea, button'),
    hidden = form.find('.foot-form-hidden'),
    focused = false,
    filled = false;

  inputs.on('focus', function() {
    focused = true;
    hidden.slideDown(300);
  }).on('blur', function() {
    focused = false;

    hideF(hidden, focused, filled);
  });

  inputs.on('input keyup keydown paste change', function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (val && val !== '') {
      filled = true;
    } else {
      filled = false;
    }
  });
});

function hideF(hid, foc, fill) {
  if (foc == false && fill == false && !hid.hasClass('hidden')) {
    hid.slideUp(300);
  }
}
```

```css
.foot-form-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-form">
  <form>
    <div class="ui-form-row">
      <div class="ui-form-field ui-form-field--100">
        <label class="ui-input ui-input--dark">
                                                <textarea class="foot-form-trigger" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>
                                            </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-form-hidden">
      <div class="ui-form-row">
        <div class="ui-form-field ui-form-field--56">
          <label class="ui-input ui-input--dark">
                                                    <input type="phone" placeholder="7 (999) 999 89 89" />
                                                </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-form-field ui-form-field--44">
          <button class="ui-btn ui-btn--white" type="button">Отправить</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Когда срабатывает фокус на одном элементе, параллельно срабатывает и blur на другом ) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121499 — на blur можно проверить, куда перешел фокус, и если новая цель тоже внутри формы, ничего не делать. И еще slideDown надо бы запускать только `if (!hidden.is(':visible'))`

Answer (score 2):

Не вижу смысла в обилии функций, вместо того, чтобы использовать нативные средства:

```js
$('.foot-form').on('focusout', function() {
  $(this).find('.foot-form-hidden').toggleClass("not-empty", ($(this).find("input").val() + $(this).find("textarea").val() != ''));
});
```

```css
.foot-form-hidden { transform-origin: top; transform: scaley(0); transition: .3s ease; }
.foot-form:focus-within .foot-form-hidden, .foot-form-hidden.not-empty { transform: scaley(1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foot-form">
  <form>
    <div class="ui-form-row">
      <div class="ui-form-field ui-form-field--100">
        <label class="ui-input ui-input--dark">
          <textarea class="foot-form-trigger" placeholder="Ваше сообщение"></textarea>
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="foot-form-hidden">
      <div class="ui-form-row">
        <div class="ui-form-field ui-form-field--56">
          <label class="ui-input ui-input--dark">
            <input type="phone" placeholder="7 (999) 999 89 89" />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-form-field ui-form-field--44">
          <button class="ui-btn ui-btn--white" type="button">Отправить</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Собственно, так и решил для себя эту проблему. Только вместо scale сделал height